# Sylvester's Criterion for indefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian-matrices

My definition of indefinite matrix is a (Hermitian) matrix with both positive and negative eigenvalues (in particular it is invertible). How can I use the leading principal minors to identify an indefinite matrix? For example take the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&4\\4&6\end{pmatrix}$, then $\Delta_1=0$ and $\Delta_2=-16$, and the eigenvalues are $8$ and $-2$, so it is indefinite.

Comment: You're specifically working with 2x2 matrix, because for 3x3 (and more) indefinite matrices could have 0-determinant (for example diag(1,0,-1)).

Comment: For the definition that I am using an indefinite matrix must be invertible.

Comment: If so, how do you classify diag(-1,0,1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a Hermitian matrix $H$ to meet your definition, it must satisfy all the following 3 conditions.
$$\text {(i)  $\exists$ negative principal minor}$$
$$\text {(ii)$\exists$ positive principal minor of odd order}$$ 
$$\text {or $\exists$ negative principal minor of even order}$$
$$\text {(iii)} \det (H) \ne 0  $$

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. E.g. all leading principal minors of $A=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&1&0}$ are zero, but $A$ is indefinite.

By Sylvester's criterion, a Hermitian matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite (resp. negative semidefinite) if **all** principal minors (not just the leading ones) of $A$ (resp. $-A$) are nonnegative. Therefore, to check that whether $A$ is indefinite or not, you need to check whether $A$ has two principal minors of different signs.

*Remark.* In your (very uncommon) definition of indefinite matrix, you require invertibility. So, you must also check that $\det(A)\ne0$.