# Is the matrix semidefinite or indefinite?

Tags: calculus, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite, hessian-matrix

We have the matrix $$H=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ I want to use the Sylvester's criterion.

The first leading principal minor is equal to $H_1=0$ and the second leading principal minor is equal to $0-1=-1<0$.

We have that not all leading principal minors are positiv so the matrix is not positively definite.

We have that we don't have the sequence $H_1<0$, $H_2>0$ and so the matrix is not negatively definite.

Therefore we either have semidefinite or indefinite, right?

How do we check what holds in this case?

Comment: Using the characteristic polynomial, you can find the eigenvalues of the matrix. Alternatively, you can look at $x^T H x$ for $x \in \mathbb R^2$ and see if this real number if always negative or always positive or sometime this sometimes that.

Comment: So in this case it is better to use the eigenvalues instead of the Sylvester's criterion because we don't have something clear? @Ramanujan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sylvester's Criterion for indefinite matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3641362/sylvesters-criterion-for-indefinite-matrices)

Comment: Ramanujan is giving a simpler criterion via the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix)...what is $[a~~ b]H[a~~ b]^T$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$? You can compute this in closed form, and decide whether or not it is always positive, always negative, or sometimes this and sometimes that...

Comment: Thank you!! :-)